# Maven. Transitive dependencies

Tags: maven-2, dependencies

My project P depends on dependency A which depends on dependency B.  My project's pom.xml file includes A as a dependency, and its jar is included in P's classpath.  However, there is a `NoClassDefFoundError` thrown at runtime of P, which stems from missing B jars.

Shouldn't Maven have downloaded these dependencies automatically?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> My project P depends on dependency A [with a compile scope] which depends on dependency B [with a compile scope].

Unless B is an [*optional dependency*](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies) of A, B should be a dependency of P with a "compile(*)" scope (see the table of [Dependency Scope](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) and read the note) and should thus be available at runtime.

> However, there is a NoClassDefFoundError thrown at runtime of P, which stems from missing B jars.

Since you're running the project under Eclipse, the class path is setup for you so I'll exclude a mistake at this level. This leaves us with the case of the optional dependency.

PS: A very useful tool to investigate this kind of problem is `dependency:tree`.

Comment: re the last sentence: The dependency hierarchy view in m2eclipse is a lot more user-friendly than dependency:tree, it even gives you an 'exclude' wizard

Comment: @seanizer: True (assuming the OP is using m2eclipse). Note that [`dependency:tree`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin) also supports [filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/filtering-the-dependency-tree.html).

Comment: I'm assuming that anybody who uses maven and eclipse together also uses m2eclipse, as it's much more powerful and comfortable than the maven-eclipse-plugin (pom editor, repository index, automatic config changes when pom was edited etc). and of course it also includes filtering: click on any artifact in the hierarchy and only this artifact's hierarchy is shown...

Comment: @Jake: I know this question is old, but i have the same problem and don't see how this answer solved the problem - can you tell me how you solved it? Btw. a workaround is to add the transitive dependencies as direct dependencies, but i would like to have "the real" solution.

Comment: @kutschkem did You figure it out yet? After all those years :)

Comment: @fane89 I can't remember if I found an actual solution, but an alternate approach to the workaround I mentioned is copying the dependencies to another directory and adding that to the classpath: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908090/downloading-all-maven-dependencies-to-a-directory-not-in-repository

Comment: @kutschkem in my case the problem was at the deployment phase. I was using `mvn deploy:deploy-file` to deploy my project to the deployment server. However, _by default_ this re-generates your `pom.xml` and destroys your project's list of dependencies! See solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58698453/maven-transitive-dependency-not-loaded

Answer (score 3):

If this dependency A has a **compile** scope - sure, it should have been downloaded and more over - made available in the classpath of the project. But if it had **provided** scope that would be the case, since provided deps would not be packaged with the application by Maven.

Btw how are you running this project - not running in the proper way might cause such problems as well and this is a very good guess. For example - if you're using maven [exec plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) - maven will setup properly the classpath for you, but otherwise - you should setup it yourself(or build a jar with dependencies with the [assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/)).

Comment: A lists B as a dependency with "compile" scope; P lists A as a dependency with "compile" scope.  B is not being added to P's classpath.

Comment: You didn't answer the question of 'how are you running it?'

Comment: @bmargulies Pardon.  I generate Eclipse metadata and run it out of the Eclipse debugger.

Comment: You generate it with mvn eclipse:eclipse?

Comment: Yes, I generate the metadata with `mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse`.  A's jar is then included in the Eclipse "Referenced Libraries" for P, but no dependency of A is included (and thus B is not included either).

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing my own solution/situation since none of the other answers solved my problem.

In my case, my project (`ME`) was dependant on another project (`LIB`) which was dependant on another project (`open-csv`).

However, I noticed an older version of `open-csv` is already a dependency in my project, and probably this force the second library (`LIB`) use this older version of `open-csv` library, which does not contain a newer class used by `LIB`.

I solved the issue by updating the version of `open-csv` in my main project dependency list.

Answer (score -3):

In my case i forgot to start Eclipse with the -vm parameter, which should point to jdk/javaw.exe.

Even after 5 Years of Java EE programming you still make greenhorn mistakes...

Comment: This is not an answer but an anecdote with no clear relation to the question.