# batik-rasterizer.jar - convert svg to png

Tags: java, php, linux, svg, exec

I was try yo setup  an export server in my linux server with the following command to download graph as image from [***Highcharts***](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server).

```
$command = "java -jar batik-rasterizer.jar -m image/png -d temp/1a6b5dd08ec607454b81f91097fb24a6.png temp/1a6b5dd08ec607454b81f91097fb24a6.svg 2>&1 "; 
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo "Command: $command <br>";
echo "Output: $output";
```

It creates an image in my local windows machine perfectly ,But i uploaded it in my linux server,I am getting errors.

```
 About to transcode 1 SVG file(s) Converting 1a6b5dd08ec607454b81f91097fb24a6.svg to temp/1a6b5dd08ec607454b81f91097fb24a6.png ... (.:21519): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Why this happens?

***And i notice that an image is created with 0 kb invalid image***

**Note:** *I have also tried the following methods*.

1)folder containing batik-rasterizer.jar and the files have owner as root and permission is set as 777.

2)i also try to execute it with **/user/bin/java** , **which java** insted pf **java** command.

3)I also try to execute this command as root using terminal using putty,Java is installed in my server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute java with the `-Djava.awt.headless=true` command-line option:

```
$command = "java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar batik-rasterizer.jar -m image/png -d temp/out.png temp/in.svg 2>&1 ";
```

**Update**

If passing the additional command-line option still does not yield the expected result, check your Java version. Updating your JRE to a more recent version (1.7) might also resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your quick rply.I try  java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar batik-rasterizer.jar -m image/png -d temp/ad7ebdfaabdbec04152c2e6decd3b40c.png temp/ad7ebdfaabdbec04152c2e6decd3b40c.svg 2>&1 ,But got the same result.

Comment: @Shin What version are you using? 1.7?

Comment: @Shin That's great news!

Comment: @Shin I saw that your edit was rejected, so I updated the answer myself.

Comment: Anyway,I accepted this as an answer,I think it will help someone facing the same problem.Thanks for your help. @Robby Cornelissen