# Parse array JSON Schema with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, schema

I have a JSON Schema defined :

```
{
  "definitions": {},
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "http://example.com/root.json",
  "type": "array",
  "title": "The Root Schema",
  "items": {
    "$id": "#/items",
    "type": "object",
    "title": "The Items Schema",
    "required": [
      "test",
      "isExpand",
      "numberOfIssue",
      "issue",
      "listOfDetails"
    ],
    "properties": {
      "test": {
        "$id": "#/items/properties/test",
        "type": "string",
        "title": "The Test Schema",
        "default": "",
        "examples": [
          "value"
        ],
        "pattern": "^(.*)$"
      },
      "isExpand": {
        "$id": "#/items/properties/isExpand",
        "type": "boolean",
        "title": "The Isexpand Schema",
        "default": false,
        "examples": [
          true
        ]
      },
      "numberOfIssue": {
        "$id": "#/items/properties/numberOfIssue",
        "type": "integer",
        "title": "The Numberofissue Schema",
        "default": 0,
        "examples": [
          1
        ]
      },
      "issue": {
        "$id": "#/items/properties/issue",
        "type": "object",
        "title": "The Issue Schema",
        "required": [
          "mappingId"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "mappingId": {
            "$id": "#/items/properties/issue/properties/mappingId",
            "type": "string",
            "title": "The Mappingid Schema",
            "default": "",
            "examples": [
              "1561561"
            ],
            "pattern": "^(.*)$"
          }
        }
      },
      "listOfDetails": {
        "$id": "#/items/properties/listOfDetails",
        "type": "array",
        "title": "The listOfDetails Schema",
        "items": {
          "$id": "#/items/properties/listOfDetails/items",
          "type": "object",
          "title": "The Items Schema",
          "required": [
            "self",
            "detailId"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "self": {
              "$id": "#/items/properties/listOfDetails/items/properties/self",
              "type": "string",
              "title": "The Self Schema",
              "default": "",
              "examples": [
                "self1"
              ],
              "pattern": "^(.*)$"
            },
            "issueId": {
              "$id": "#/items/properties/listOfDetails/items/properties/detailId",
              "type": "string",
              "title": "The detailId Schema",
              "default": "",
              "examples": [
                "000188181"
              ],
              "pattern": "^(.*)$"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It'll always be a schema which contains firstly **items** and then it'll contain **properties**.
In properties can be more arrays or objects found so I want to do that recursively.
What i'm trying to achieve is a `Map<String, Object>` which directly represents the schema. Where I'm getting stuck is the recursive call where current property is a object or array.

I want to achieve this:

```
{
  "test" : "",
   "isExpand" : false,
   "numberOfIssues" : 0,
   "issue" : {
      "mappingId" : ""
    },
   "listOfDetails" : [
     {
      "self" : "",
      "detailId" : ""
     }
    ]
}
```

Here is my method for parsing out the JsonSchema from file and getting the actual properties from it

```
    private static void parseJsonNode(String path) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new JsonFactory());
        JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(new File(METADATA_SCHEMA_PATH + path));
        Map<String, Object> elementsMap = new HashMap<>();
        fillHashMap(elementsMap, rootNode.get("items").get("properties"));
    }
```

The `elementsMap` is a `Map<String, Object>` defined globally

```
Map<String, Object> elementsMap = new HashMap<>();
```

```
private static Map<String, Object> fillHashMap(Map<String, Object> elementsMap, JsonNode rootNode) throws Exception {
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> fieldsIterator = rootNode.fields();
        while (fieldsIterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> field = fieldsIterator.next();
            if (field.getValue().get("type").toString().contains("array")) {
                //TODO HOW TO HANDLE ARRAY THERE
            } else if (field.getValue().get("type").toString().contains("object")) {
                elementsMap.put(field.getKey(), fillHashMap(elementsMap, field.getValue().get("properties")));
            } else {
                elementsMap.put(field.getKey(), field.getValue().get("default"));
            }
        }
        return elementsMap;
}
```

I'm getting stuck on the recursive call fillHashMap(). When i unbox the object properties it goes to else branch where it puts the **mappingId** directly to the Map, which is logical after unboxing.. but i'm guessing that i'm doing it all wrong.. Can someone point me on the things which I should change in order to achieve my desired result? Thanks !!

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/36127186/8112217

Comment: @tsarenkotxt I had.. actually on the example with foreach, but it's not working the expected way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself. Maybe it'll once help someone.

```
private static void parseJsonNode(String path) throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new JsonFactory());
    JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(new File(BASE_PATH + path));
    Map<String, Object> elementsMap =
        fillHashMap(rootNode.get("items").get("properties"));
    System.out.println(elementsMap);
}
```

```
private static Map<String, Object> fillHashMap(JsonNode rootNode) {
    Map<String, Object> elementsMap = new HashMap<>();
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> fieldsIterator = rootNode.fields();
    while (fieldsIterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> field = fieldsIterator.next();
        if (field.getValue().get("type").toString().contains("array")) {
            List<Map<String, Object>> objectArray = new ArrayList<>();
            JsonNode itemsNode = field.getValue().get("items").get("properties");
            objectArray.add(fillHashMap(itemsNode));
            elementsMap.put(field.getKey(), objectArray);
        } else if (field.getValue().get("type").toString().contains("object")) {
            elementsMap.put(field.getKey(),
                 fillHashMap(field.getValue().get("properties")));
        } else {
            elementsMap.put(field.getKey(), field.getValue().get("default"));
        }
    }
    return elementsMap;
}
```