# having trouble running my selenium script from testng through CMD when the jars are added as a maven dependency

Tags: java, selenium, cmd, testng

Guys I am trying to integrate run my TestNG selenium script through command line by entering the following command

```
java -cp C:\Users\designuser\workspace\data_verification\bin;C:\Users\designuser\workspace\data_verification\lib\* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

and get the following Error:

> Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG

The problem is that I have added all the jars as maven a dependency in my project hence the lib folder dose not exist in my project.

If I manually download a `testNg` jar and add it to my current project the command works fine.

Now, how do I achieve the same when I have added `testNg` as a maven dependency?

Comment: well, you need to download the maven dependencies. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908090/downloading-all-maven-dependencies-to-a-directory-not-in-repository