# Is there a way to build a java app and export dependencies in different folders with maven?

Tags: java, maven, build

I have a maven desktop application which contains thirdy-party and my own dependencie projects (Business, Repository and GUI). I want to be able to build the application with the below folder structure:

```
    App.jar
    AppBusiness.jar
    AppRepository.jar
    AppGUI.jar
    lib(folder)
      - the rest of thirdy-party jars in lib folder
        (hibernate, jackson, drivers, etc..)
```

Can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Downloading all maven dependencies to a directory NOT in repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908090/downloading-all-maven-dependencies-to-a-directory-not-in-repository)

Comment: This sounds like a job for [maven-assembly-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) which creates an archive (tar.gz, zip etc.) which can be unpackaged and produces the required structure

Answer (score 1):

You can use the maven dependency [plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html) to copy the dependencies to the chosen directory and then zip/tar it as per need.

Comment: But I want to copy some dependencies in the lib folder and some others in another folder.

Comment: Assumed you want the project artefacts in target and rest of the dependencies in the lib folder. If we want control on copying specific jars/dependencies the dependency plugin has the configuration to support selecting specific items, see the [example](https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-dependency-plugin-2.6/examples/copying-artifacts.html) here.

You also can use the [antrun](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/tasks/dependencyFilesets.html) to copy things around

Comment: With your link I could copy specific jars to specific paths as I wanted. But I got a new problem: The classpath. Do you have some idea how I can configure it to include my custom path jars?

Comment: Where do you want to set the classpath? If you want maven to manage the dependencies, we don't need to separately copy the jars to a separate folder. If however, we are distributing this, and some other apps to rely on this, options are - <ul>
     - set the lib folder in classpath, as well as the dir having application jars e.g. java -cp {path to lib}/* {main class}
    - If we use an ide simply add the jars folder
    - if another project is also maven based, multiple [examples](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html)
 </ul>