Groovy add column value in csv file
I need to export JSON in csv file. how to add values ​​to each column? I know how to add rows. Here's an example code:
def data = [
        ['place', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'team'],
        ['1', 'Lorena', 'Wiebes', 'Team DSM'],
        ['2', 'Marianne', 'Vos', 'Team Jumbo Visma'],
        ['3', 'Lotte', 'Kopecky', 'Team SD Worx']
]
def file = new File("C:/Temp/data.csv")
file.text = data*.join(',').join(System.lineSeparator())

Result:

I need result:

Please suggest good literature on Groovy with examples, thank you.

Your problem isn't groovy, it's that Excel is a POS https://superuser.com/questions/238944/how-to-force-excel-to-open-csv-files-with-data-arranged-in-columns

@tim_yates thanks very much :)) Please fill out the answer, I will mark it as correct, if it is not difficult, you will get + points?

@tim_yates can retire on the points he has already :)

POS +1.  I'm here to talk trash about Excel and CSVs now. ;-)

def data = [
        ['place', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'team'],
        ['1', 'Lorena', 'Wiebes', 'Team DSM'],
        ['2', 'Marianne', 'Vos', 'Team Jumbo Visma'],
        ['3', 'Lotte', 'Kopecky', 'Team SD Worx']
]
    def file = new File("C:/Temp/data.csv")

    def stringBuilder = new StringBuilder()
    data.each { row ->
    stringBuilder.append(row.join(';')).append(System.lineSeparator())
    }

    file.text = stringBuilder.toString()


You need to Iterate over the data object and append each row with lineSeparator() and i would also suggest to use StringBuilder
def stringBuilder = new StringBuilder()
data.each { row ->
stringBuilder.append(row.join(',')).append(System.lineSeparator())
}

// Write the contents to the file
file.text = stringBuilder.toString()


Not help your code.

what is the issue ? it worked for me

the project was built without errors, but the result is the same.

@RyuzakiL I think your code generates the exact same output as the code in the question...

If you are willing to use another library you can add this to your program:
https://github.com/chubbard/gratum
To read json data you can do the following:
JsonSource.json(new File("xxx.json")).into()                           // 1
   .addField("salutation") { row -> "Hello ${row['column1']}" }        // 2
   .save( new File("xxxx.csv", ","))                                   // 3
   .go()                                                               // 4


Parse a Json file, this would assume an array as a top level object.  Other options let you parse a top level object that isn't an array or parse an array nested inside another top level object.
adds a field called salutation to the row.  In this case it creates a string that combines a literal with something from column1 in the objects from JSON.
writes the pipeline to a CSV file with a comma separator
Starts the pipeline processing data.


Hello @chubbsondubs, I can't not see how add to Eclipse project? Need to .jar-file.

So you'll probably want to use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908090/downloading-all-maven-dependencies-to-a-directory-not-in-repository to get the respective jar files.  You could download it from maven, but you would be missing its dependencies so that procedure will download everything you need.  The other option is just adopt maven or gradle.
