# mvn dependency not recognised after dependency version change

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have a custom dependency for my project, `api-client`. This dependency is used to connect among multiple modules within my project.

The problem is, if I make any changes in my `api-client` dependency and I produce a `.jar` file using the below command:

```
mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

I will place that `.jar` file in my `.m2 repository` manually. Afterwards, if I try to run other modules which depends on `api-client`, those modules
would throw lots of compilation errors. (Previously, all ran successfully.)

Some of the sample errors are as follows:

```
[ERROR] /C:/Local/core/src/main/java/com/core/service/impl/DBSClaimServiceImpl.java:[33,39] C:\Local\core\src\main\java\com\core\service\impl\DBSClaimServiceImpl.java:33: package org.apache.commons.lang3 does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Local/core/src/main/java/com/core/service/impl/DBSClaimServiceImpl.java:[33,1] C:\Local\core\src\main\java\com\core\service\impl\DBSClaimServiceImpl.java:33: static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /C:/Local/core/src/main/java/com/core/model/Dealer.java:[9,39] C:\Local\core\src\main\java\com\core\model\Dealer.java:9: package org.apache.commons.lang3 does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Local/core/src/main/java/com/core/model/Dealer.java:[9,1] C:\Local\core\src\main\java\com\core\model\Dealer.java:9: static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /C:/Local/core/src/main/java/com/core/resource/settlement/flatFile/RecordType1ClaimInformation.java:[10,39] C:\Local\core\src\main\java\com\core\resource\settlement\flatFile\RecordType1ClaimInformation.java:10: package org.apache.commons.lang3 does not exist
```

All the packages are available in my local repository, but still, it is not recognising them. I am unsure what exactly the problem is here.

Below please find entries that I have in one of the module:

```
<api.version>1.0.245</api.version>
<api.client.version>1.0.292</api.client.version>
```

The problem started once I changed the above version (`api.client.version`). After that, an old version also throws the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven - Transitive dependencies are not resolved for artifact deployed on Artifactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43999612/maven-transitive-dependencies-are-not-resolved-for-artifact-deployed-on-artifa)

Answer (score 0):

To resolve transitive dependencies, other modules do not just need the `api-client.jar`, but also a generated `pom.xml` which declares what other jars are needed to use api-client.jar.

There are multiple ways to fix this, but the description of your environment is not detailed enough to tell how best to fix this.