# Maven transitive dependency not loaded

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, dependencies, slf4j

**Problem**: When I import the jar of a custom logging library in another application, I would like that the custom library contains the dependency on **slf4j** without to have to put this dependency in the application.

I have a Maven project **my-logger** that depends on **log4j-slf4j-impl**, on the **pom.xml** of **my-logger** :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.12.1</version>
</dependency>
```

In my Spring Boot project **my-app**, I import **my-logger** :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-logger</artifactId>
  <version>100</version>
</dependency>
```

But in IntelliJ I don't see any dependency under **org.test:my-logger:100**

And I have to add a **log4j-slf4j-impl** dependency in **my-app** pom.xml or I get a

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"
```

The pom.xml of **my-logger** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-logger</artifactId>
    <version>100</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>my-logger</name>
    <description>Logging app</description>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The pom.xml of **my-app** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>my-app</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.test</groupId>
             <artifactId>my-logger</artifactId>
             <version>100</version>
         </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Maven automatically resolves transitive dependencies unless you change the scope or mark it optional. Could you add the POMs to your question as well?

Comment: (I have added the POMs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I did a maven deploy (see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) to nexus I was using the option `generatePom=true` and the generated `.pom` file didn’t contain the transitive dependencies.
When I added the option `pomFile=pom.xml` the transitive dependencies were added to the .pom file generated and it worked.

Comment: You can confirm if this is your issue by checking the deployment server (Nexus/Artifactory/etc.) and looking at the POM file that is included with your deployed code. You should see your whole POM file here. If the POM file is very simple, then it's getting re-generated!

Comment: It would seem that `-DgeneratePom` is `true` by default! Adding the switch `-DpomFile=pom.xml` solved the problem for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the `spring-boot-starter-parent` changes the scope of `log4j-slf4j-impl` to something like `provided`. You can figure that out by looking at `mvn dependency:tree` where you will find the resulting scope and version of `log4j-slf4j-impl`.

Comment: after running `mvn dependency:tree`, `log4j-slf4j-impl` is not in the tree

Comment: That is strange. Look for snippets containing `log4j-slf4j-impl` in the parent POM.